# ¿Cómo ordenar un DF de acuerdo al orden en un vector?

Tags: r

Tengo un `data.frame` ordendado de acuerdo a la variable `x`. Y tengo un vector `xo` con los mismos valores de la columna `df$x` pero con un orden determinado. Lo que intento lograr es ordenar el `df` tal que variable `x` tenga el mismo orden que `xo.

```
xo<-c(45, 41, 69, 31, 58, 87, 36, 97, 75, 14)
df<-data.frame(x=sort(xo),y=1:10)
> df
    x  y
1  14  1
2  31  2
3  36  3
4  41  4
5  45  5
6  58  6
7  69  7
8  75  8
9  87  9
10 97 10
> xo
 [1] 45 41 69 31 58 87 36 97 75 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `match` para ubicar las posiciones del vector `xo` dentro de `df$x`, si luego usas este dato para seleccionar las filas, gracias a que el orden de selección sería el de `xo`, logramos el objectivo:

```
df[match(xo, df$x), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas es:

```
merge(data.frame(x = xo), df, all.x = TRUE, sort = F)
```

Creamos un df con la variable x = x0 para que tenga el orden deseado y luego un cruce left para traer lo que hay contenido en y, así no perdemos el orden

los parámetros `all.x = TRUE` son para especificar un cruce **left** y `sort = F` para que la data no la reordene